# Como o código abaixo ficaria em JavaScript puro?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com uma certa dificuldade para encontrar uma forma de uma função encontrar uma variável de outra função dentro do meu código à medida que digito dentro de uma caixa de texto, mesmo a variável sendo global. Vou tentar através do código abaixo, mas preciso antes convertê-lo em JS puro.

```
$('input[name="q"]').keyup(function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar `.querySelector()` para buscar o elemento e usar `.addEventListener()` para observar o event **"keyup"** no elemento alvo (`<input>`)

O trecho abaixo expressa este raciocinio:

```js
document.querySelector('input[name="q"]').addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.value);
}, false);
```

```html
<input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Digite aqui">
```

Caso não encontre um elemento `.querySelector()` retorna `null` e por isso lançará um erro (`TypeError`) ao tentar vincular um ouvinte de **"evento"** ... exemplo:

```js
    document.querySelector('input[name="q"]').addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {
        console.log(evt.target.value);
    }, false);
```

```html
<input name="xyz" type="text" placeholder="Digite aqui">
```

Para não correr o risco de tentar anexar um ouvinte a uma referencia que não existe (`null`), você pode referenciar o elemento em uma variável e então verificar se ela "existe" (se o elemento foi encontrado), exemplo:

```js
    let inputElement = document.querySelector('input[name="q"]');
    // verificar
    if ( inputElement ) {
        inputElement.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {
            console.log(evt.target.value);
        }, false);
    }
```

```html
<input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Digite aqui">
```

---

**Fontes**:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError

Comment: Bem claro e elucidativo, Lauro! Muito obrigado!